# How to start a counter for a setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, hoisting

I have this code working, but I'd like to improve it:

```
var c = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
//this is called as an object method I created
var animar = function () {
   var obj = this;//saves the object that called it to later access to its properties
   var counter= 0;
   var animacion = setInterval(function(){
            c.save()
            c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            c.rotate(0.1*counter);
            obj.pintar();
            c.restore();
            counter++;

   }, 50);
}
```

I'd like to use a outter function for posible future use but when I change the code I have, there is a hoisting problem and I don't know how to get  the counter inside the rotar() function without overwriting it all the time:

```
var animar = function () {
    var obj = this;
    var counter= 0;
    var animacion = setInterval(function(){
        rotar(obj)
    }, 50);
}

function rotar (obj) {
    c.save()
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.rotate(0.1*counter);
    obj.pintar();
    c.restore();
    counter++;
}
```

I get that the first one works because they are nested, while in the second example isn't. How can I have a counter for the setInterval **WITHOUT USING A GLOBAL VARIABLE**?
(I mean... if I call it a second time, it will not start in 0. If I set it to be 0 in the animar() function, it would work, but then I'd need to set it to 0 in every function that uses a counter or using counters with diferent names. This two posibilities don't sound good.)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to put `var counter = 0` outside the functions:

```
var counter;
var animar = function () {
    var obj = this;
    counter = 0; // reset every time before 'animacion'...
    var animacion = setInterval(function(){
        rotar(obj)
    }, 50);
}
function rotar (obj) {
    c.save()
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.rotate(0.1*contador);
    obj.pintar();
    c.restore();
    counter++;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want a global variable, you can follow Walter's answer, or do this:

```
var animar = function () {
    var obj = this;
    var counter = 0; // new variable every time animar() is called
    var animacion = setInterval(function(){
        rotar(obj, counter);
        counter++;
    }, 50);
}
function rotar (obj, counter) {
    c.save()
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.rotate(0.1*contador);
    obj.pintar();
    c.restore();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I specified at the end of the question that it should be without using a global counter.

Comment: I mean... if I call it a second time, it will not start in 0. If I set it to be 0 in the animar() function, it would work, but then I'd need to set it to 0 in every function that uses a counter or using counters with diferent names. This two posibilities don't sound good.

Comment: Updated to reset to 0... if you still don't want counter to be outside (why?), I can update again... but can you tell me why first?

Comment: I don't know enough of this to say if this is commonly done like this, with a global counter that is reset every time a function needs a counter, but it doesn't seem elegant to me. It is very easy to forget about reseting it latter on. But maybe there is no better way, that is why I'm asking if there is.

Comment: I updated to add a way to do it without global vars, or you can follow Walter's way. All of those are valid IMO, the choice comes down to context etc.

Comment: All that said, why do you need counter in `rotar()`? You're not using it anywhere in your current function, except to increment it? You may need to pass it to your `save()` or `pintar()` function or wherever you might need it...

Comment: You are right! I think that is the way! THank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

make `counter` scoped inside of your `animar` object:

```
var animar = function () {
    var obj = this;
    obj.counter= 0;
    var animacion = setInterval(function(){
        rotar(obj)
    }, 50);
}

function rotar (obj) {
    c.save()
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.rotate(0.1*obj.counter);
    obj.pintar();
    c.restore();
    obj.counter++;
}
```